# Add table into custom cell in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have to use subTable into cell of another table as shown in given in image
Please help me out
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Download [source code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html) from here..
This is a demo sample from apple...

Happy coding...

Answer (score 2):

Download [source code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html) from here. It is demo application from Apple itself. You will find how to get your requirement done int that sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the level, you just add one extra column to differentiate b/w section and subsection for example

```
int level = (it may be 1 for section and 2 for subsection)
if(level == 1){
   cell.textLabel.text = @"WA"
}
else{
    cell.textLabel.text = @"    Metro" //give extra space
}
```